# How to Populate jQuery Object with Data from Link Inside HTML List?

Tags: jquery, object

I have a list that looks like this:

```
<ul id="theLinks">
 <li><a href="one.php">One</a></li>
 <li><a href="two.php">Two</a></li>
 <li><a href="three.php">Three</a></li>
 <li><a href="four.php">Four</a></li>
</ul>
```

I would like to populate a jQuery Object with the data from that list so it looks like this:

```
var Links = {
  'One'   : 'one.php',
  'Two'   : 'two.php',
  'Three' : 'three.php',
  'Four'  : 'four.php' 
}
```

What is the best method for solving this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var Links = {};
$('#theLinks li a').each(function(){
    Links[this.innerHTML] = this.href.substring(this.href.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
});
```

[Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/jruddell/ypDM7/)

**Note:** the links will not be in order because this is not an array.

**Outputs**:

```
Four: "four.php"
One: "one.php"
Three: "three.php"
Two: "two.php"
```

Answer (score 1):

Not tested, but something like this:

```
var Links = {};
$('#theLinks li a').each(function(index, value) {         
    Links[value.text()] = value.attr('href');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your result isn't an array, it's an object. (And it's nothing to do with jQuery, it's a straight JavaScript object. :-) )

Here's how you'd do that:

```
var Links = {};
$('#theLinks > li > a').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    Links[$this.text()] = $this.attr('href');
});
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/omane3)

Note I've used a fairly restrictive selector, `#theLinks > li > a` (an `a` *only* when it's the direct child of an `li` *only* when it's the direct child of `#theLinks`). You could use a looser one if your structure may vary slightly, such as `#theLinks li a` which allows for intermediate elements between both the `ul` and the `li`s and between the `li`s and the `a`s. It depends entirely on what you want to achieve. But with the markup you gave, I'd probably be fairly tight about it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = {};
$("#theLinks a").map( function() {obj[$(this).text()] = this.href });
alert(obj.One);
alert(obj.Two);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/9SPUY/